# Getting MD5 certificate on mac

Tags: android, xcode, terminal, md5

someone can tell me why this command

keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/Desktop/release-1.keystore -storepass android -keypass android

fail with error

keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect.

Where am i mistaken.. please give me an example where i can get MD5 code on mac os.

Answer (score 0):

Try the password as android itself. Maybe it will work. Actually that works for me and i think its the default password for keystore.